# Trix rendering html tags such as div and br tags in Django

Tags: django, trix

I am using Trix as a rich text editor in Django, however i run into a problem, when going to save the data,

If i type, Hey **trix check**, it will return  **trix check**  backk

and it also adds br tags as well, if you want to check it can be seen on
[www.brogrow.in](http://www.brogrow.in)

Can anyone help on it?

For login you can use -
Username - new &
password - Nov@2020

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the [safe](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#safe) filter in your template that display the content with the div and br tags. It should not display the HTML content of your blog posts.

Comment: Hey tried the safe tag, doesn't seem to work
guess it's taking <div> as an element and not a tag :(

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyM3_kdD-wY&ab_channel=GoRails
This guy bypassed it by using <% sanitize @post.body %>
Can this be done in django?